# Gubicorn/Nginx does not download files completely: [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:18)

Tags: nginx, web-server, django, gunicorn

I am running a django app with nginx in docker. I can download files via an API using the library `requests`. When I want to download a file with 55 MB somehow the connection breaks down and the download doesn't finish.

I tried tweaking nginx configs like this but still the download does not succeed:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        use epoll;
        multi_accept off;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    send_timeout       7200;
    keepalive_timeout  7200;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 7200;
    proxy_read_timeout 7200;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

I also tried to set the workers higher but it is not recommended in the docs. I set the values of

```
send_timeout       7200;
    keepalive_timeout  7200;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 7200;
    proxy_read_timeout 7200;
```

very high so the server doesn't close the connection. But the download still breaks after like 27 MB.

Is there any config that would cause this?

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks so much in advance.

EDIT: I can download the file with a fast internet connection in the browser. But when the connection is slow it breaks. But I need to be able to download files with a slower connection too..

EDIT2: Trailing the logs in real time I got a  [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:18) . Is that nginx related?

Comment: no idea anyone?

Comment: solve by increasing timeout of gunicorn adding ``--timeout 120 --graceful-timeout 60``